# Shared Facebook Access Token between Website and Mobile Application

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, access-token, facebook-access-token

I would like a Web site (Rails 3.1 with Devise and Omniauth) and a mobile application (iOS5) to share authentication. By this I mean I would like a user to be able to SSI to the site with Facebook, or SSI to the mobile application and have the mobile application talk to the website's API using the user's credentials to authenticate to the website.

I currently have the web side working nicely with a User being able to SSI to an account. I also have the mobile application working, supporting user SSI. Both are using the same Facebook application.

My problem is finding something shared between the two that I can use for the Mobile application to authenticate against the site. Obviously both have access to the same user ID, but this doesn't seem very secure. My mobile application has an Access Token, but this differs from the website's access token, though they look similar, and my mobile access token expires while my web access token does not.

Web/Rails Token (Not real):

> DDDAKnu1dg40BDHEWN0VDssxs8GGF8ZBEEOb38HnS0IUEQC1NSufmPCcGeFkTuw39ZDl7OhlZBD2jwJEqXdAZCtZBflJRQKZB4ZA

Mobile/iOS Token (Not real)

> BDDAKnu1dg40BDEo3YjZD2hIwjfZB4slXJj3fmHfzLh5q1xZD0ShfJCb6PMjnApkpM0FTuGGvWnzZBQy4GZCMuysEEqhMz8YgruD53TXKTZC0GPFkfVe0b6fe8wieLLOZDDZA

Using Facebook's [access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_tokentoken?q=BAADKnu7dg40BAEo3YjZA2hIxjfZB4slXJj3fmHfzLh5q7wZA0ShfJCb6PMjnDpkpM0FTuGGvWnzZBQy4GZCMuysEEqhMz8YgruA53TXKTZC0GPFkfVe0b6fe8xieLLOZAAZD) I get the following (Everything removed is identical between tokens):

For Web/Rails Token:

```
App ID: 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX : SomeAppName
User ID:    
XXXXXXXX : My Name
Issued: 
1327507734 : 8:08 am Jan 25 2012
Expires:    
Never
Valid:  True
Origin: Web
Scopes: email offline_access
```

For Mobile/iOS:

```
App ID: 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX : SomeAppName
Metadata:   {"sso":"iphone-safari"}
User ID:    
XXXXXXXX : My Name
Issued: 
1327507734 : 8:08 am Jan 25 2012
Expires:    
Never
Valid:  True
Origin: Native Mobile
Scopes: email offline_access
```

Comment: hello. did you find a solution to this problem? i'm facing the same issue right now...

Comment: Hi. No unfortunately not. Strange given that it would appear to be quite a common requirement. Spent a long time looking but found nothing useful. Moved onto something else but going to have to solve this pretty soon.

Comment: My application doesn't have very stringent security requirements, but, what we do is simply check with Facebook to find the user id associated with each access token to match up accounts

Comment: @alex Any luck? How have you solved it?

Comment: @JeffS Thanks. How does your website know that communications from the app are authentic - that they are coming from the app and therefore the uid it contains can be trusted?

Comment: @1ndivisible The app sends the authtoken, and the server fetches the associated UID. This does leave the server open to replay attacks (however the tokens have relatively short lives), or an attacker somehow correctly guessing a valid authtoken, however, for my purposes this was enough.

Comment: @JeffS How do you deal with the async nature of this setup - If I am understanding this right the flow is app->server->facebook api(For UID)->server->app. Given that the response from the Facebook API will be async, how does the server respond to the app?

Comment: I do this all in a blocking fashion. I don't actually use any built in library, and simply handle the requests myself. In that case, a simple call to graph.facebook.com/me and parsing of some JSON is all that is needed.

Comment: @JeffS thanks for taking the time to reply. One more question.  I'm assuming you're connecting over HTTPS. Couldn't you use a key to verify your app, then use the userID to compare users. This would remove the need for checking the user key as you could trust the comms from the device and be sure that user had been authenticated.

Comment: @1ndivisible That would work so long as you can trust that no one will be able to get the secret from your app, which on android is not at all guaranteed. In general, I don't like to trust data not coming from within a system.

Comment: @JeffS. Yep. Never trust the client.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, the way I have ended up handling this is to pass the mobile token to the server and have the server check the token's authenticity. Once this is confirmed I can check authenticate against my records using uid and email.

Comment: I have the same question now. I didn't understand your answer - if the token is not the same for login in from app and web - how do you validate it? let's say one logged from the app - how do you use it in the web calls?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do small change in facebook API, in authorization, change from

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

To

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

Because somethimes there is problem with token when you want to auth by fbApp or Safari. I had this same problem, token in my web services was different because of this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible method to solve this is to authenticate via facebook on mobile then send the an encrypted f_uid over to the rails app which will then decrypt the f_uid and see who is actually logging into the server.